# validating CSS structure as standard rule

Tags: css

I have created one page. Which contains three thing.

1. Email invitation
2. video
3. Facebook like plugin

I have created table structure and place them in thee columns.
I think something wrong. Position of element does not remain fixed.

Initially when page loaded, only invite box appear in center and video on right.

In few second when like plugin gets loaded, mail invitation box in middle section move down.

Is there any logical mistake in structure?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>
        _/Invitation@xyz\_
    </title>    
    <style>
            .header{
                background-color: #61B329;
                color: #FFF;
                margin-top: 0px !important;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                padding-bottom: 9px;
            }

            .middle{
        align:left;
            }

            .left{

            }
            .page-header-text {
                padding-left: 15px;
                padding-top: 20px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                margin: 0px;
            }


            html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0 }
        </style>
</head>
<body onload="start();">
    <div class="page-header header">
    <h1 class="page-header-text">that test</h1>
    </div>
        <table border="0.1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:20%">
            <div class="left">      
            </div>
        </td>               
        <td style="width:60%">          
            <div class="middle">
                <div id="main">
                    <form action="./submit.php" method="post">
                        <div class="bar">
                            <input id="input" placeholder="     E-mail"  name="email" type="text" />
                            <input id="but"" type="button" value="Go !!!"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>      
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="width:20%">                  
            <div class="right">
                <video width="400" height="360" controls preload="none">
                    <!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
                    <source src="1.MP4" type="video/mp4" /><!-- WebKit video    -->
                    <source src="__VIDEO__.webm" type="video/webm" /><!-- Chrome / Newest versions of Firefox and Opera -->
                    <source src="__VIDEO__.OGV" type="video/ogg" /><!-- Firefox / Opera -->
                    <!-- fallback to Flash: -->
                    <object width="640" height="384" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="__FLASH__.SWF">
                    <!-- Firefox uses the `data` attribute above, IE/Safari uses the param below -->
                    <param name="movie" value="__FLASH__.SWF" />
                    <param name="flashvars" value="image=__POSTER__.JPG&amp;file=__VIDEO__.MP4" />
                    <!-- fallback image. note the title field below, put the title of the video there -->
                    <img src="__VIDEO__.JPG" width="640" height="360" alt="__TITLE__"
                         title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
                    </object>
                </video>                
            </div>
        </td>       
    </tr>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: one won't be able to help you much unless you create a fiddle

Comment: You have a typo. `<input id="but" " type="button " value="Go !!! "/>` should be `<input id="but" type="button " value="Go !!! "/>`. Anyway, what plugin are you using?

Comment: @San: ok, but I could not create is vecause for that need to upload video and all. Wanted to know whether css style is in correct way or not

Comment: @nkmol: that is ok. Could you pleaase tell me any bug in design?

Comment: The bug you describe? no. "In few second when like **plugin gets loaded...**" Again, what plugin are you talking about? You seem to know where it comes from.